# Issues with matching width and height

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to build this layout

[image]

But I am getting this: (The map button in the location would be ideal height and width but the textview doesn't match the height)

[image]

My location is a `TextView` and my destination is a `EditText`

I want the  `TextView` and `EditText`  to be the same width while the MAP buttons stay "square".

How can I get the textviews height to match and make a square map button?

Here is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.mycompany.controller.DetailsFragment">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewStatus"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <!-- LOCATION -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="LOCATION"
                android:textColor="@color/COLOR_BLUE"
                android:textSize="24sp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutLocation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".8"
                    android:background="@color/COLOR_LIGHT_GREY"
                    android:text="123 MAIN ST., CHATTANOOGA TN 37404"
                    android:textSize="24sp"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnMapLocation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:background="@color/COLOR_BLUE"
                    android:text="MAP"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_WHITE"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- DESTINATION -->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="DESTINATION"
                android:textColor="@color/COLOR_BLUE"
                android:textSize="24sp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutDestination"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editDestination"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".8"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:text="407 Broad St., Anywhere ST 00000"/>


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnMapDestination"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:background="@color/COLOR_BLUE"
                    android:text="MAP"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_WHITE"/>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Using weights will never guarantee that things will be square, the point is they stretch to fill a certain size in relation to the layout orientation (in this case horizontal). If you want something to be square, you will need to either explicitly set the width and height, or you will need to get the measured height once the view has been drawn and set the width to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a slight modification in your code check it!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           >


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <!-- LOCATION -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="LOCATION"

            android:textSize="24sp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/searchText"
                android:text="Search text here"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="#c8c8c8"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/searchButton"
                android:text="MAP"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                />
             />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- DESTINATION -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="DESTINATION"

            android:textSize="24sp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchText"
                android:text="Search text"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/searchButton"
                android:text="MAP"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `android:layout_weight`, set `android:layout_width="0dp"`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.mycompany.controller.DetailsFragment">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewStatus"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <!-- LOCATION -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="LOCATION"
                android:textColor="@color/COLOR_BLUE"
                android:textSize="24sp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutLocation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".8"
                    android:background="@color/COLOR_LIGHT_GREY"
                    android:text="123 MAIN ST., CHATTANOOGA TN 37404"
                    android:textSize="24sp"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnMapLocation"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:background="@color/COLOR_BLUE"
                    android:text="MAP"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_WHITE"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- DESTINATION -->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="DESTINATION"
                android:textColor="@color/COLOR_BLUE"
                android:textSize="24sp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutDestination"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editDestination"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".8"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:text="407 Broad St., Anywhere ST 00000"/>


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnMapDestination"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:background="@color/COLOR_BLUE"
                    android:text="MAP"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_WHITE"/>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```